How does a cpu communicate with display devices like monitor?
I have a series of questions:
How does a cpu communicate with monitor?
Where is the display related information stored?
How does it know which part of the screen to update?
It would be of great help if someone could explain this in detail or provide some resources from where I can learn about this.
I have searched but I'm struggling to find the right resources. Please help me.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/94009/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29673/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43336/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/149203/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/46870/755

@D.W. thanks a lot!
